# Restangular with django rest framework and status of 400

Tags: angularjs, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, restangular

I'm creating new user in Django, but when i try to add user with existing email i get 400 status and

```
{
    "email": ["This field must be unique."]
}
```

And got this in console:
[image: errors]
I use this config for Angular and Django

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
});
```

This is how I've trying to handle this error on POST

```
var users = Restangular.all('users');
        users.post({
            email: $scope.email,
            first_name: $scope.firstname,
            last_name: $scope.lastname,
            phone: $scope.phone,
            password: $scope.password
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            alert("done");
        },function(response) {
            console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
        });
```

Versions:

```
Django==1.8.4
djangorestframework==3.2.4
"angular": "1.4.7",
"restangular": "1.5.1"
```

Any ideas?
**UPD**
Model serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PUser
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = PUser(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
            phone=validated_data['phone']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

PUser model is copy of Django AbstractUser, but without username and email is required and unique

Comment: Please post your serializer.

Comment: Are you wanting to update an existing user?  A `POST` is for creating, not updating.  The error is a database constraint in the Django model definition of `User`.  You can't have 2 users with the same email address.

Comment: Updated post with models.
I'm creating new users and that all working fine, but i need to handle errors when email in already used

Comment: suggest you check before trying to insert and return a more meaningful response

Comment: DRF is already checking before inserting.  That's why he's getting the 400 response.  I would say that he just needs to handle that response in his error handler.

Comment: How can i handle this errors??Why `).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            alert("done");
        },function(response) {
            console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
        });`
not working

Comment: Only by inspecting the printscreen - did you included lodash at the beginning of your scripts section of index.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the 400 error by inspecting the response in the 2nd function passed in to the `then` callback registration function. This second parameter is the error handler callback function:

```
users.post({[...]}).then(
    // success server response handler
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
        alert("done");
    },
    // failure/error server response handler
    function(response) {
        // debugger;  // breakpoint for observing error responses
        if (response.data['email'] === 'This field must be unique.']) {
            // handle the duplicate email issue
            // e.g. display a warning, or a popover, or whatever.
        } else {
            console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
        }
    });
```

If the data doesn't look exactly like the above, then inspect the exact error:

- open the debugger ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> in chrome )
- uncomment the `debugger;` line above
- reload the page
- send a new user `POST` request that has a duplicate email address
- inspect the response from the server in the debugger

Tweak the error response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was near...and the reason was with lodash package, but not standard one.
I was using "**lodash-custom-restangular**": "0.0.5" via npm and restangular works fine enough...except this stange behavior.
i've downloaded lodash with bower and all works as expected.
Thx to all.